# Convergence In Probability for Countable r.v.s

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Given $X_n \to X$ and $Y_n \to Y$ in probability, then $(X_n, Y_n) \to (X, Y)$ in probability. Now, let us consider $X_{in}$ such that for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $X_{in} \to X_i$ in probability. Is it then true that
$$(X_{1n}, X_{2n}, \ldots, X_{in}, \ldots) \to (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n, \ldots)$$
in probability?
It seems similar to the idea of functional convergence, where perhaps some type of uniform convergence is necessary. But, at the same time, I find it hard to find a counterexample. The secondary question would then be, though, what additional conditions are needed for the above statement to be true?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: There is an equivalence $Y_n \to Y$ in probability if and only if for any subsequwnce$(n_k)$ you can choose further subsequence $(n_{k_m})$ such that $Y_{n_{k_m}} \to Y$ almost surely. Use it with your countably many sequences and try to use Cantor diagonal argument to find good subsequence in your case